# Image grows with browser width?

Tags: jquery, css, image, browser, resize

Heee,
I had a question; does anybody know how you can let a background image grow with the browser in terms of Width and perhaps height as well. What do i mean? I have two great examples here;

## 1 http://www.google.com/nexus/7/

## 2 http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

That is kinda what I'm looking for... For now my image only stays centered..
*I don't use bootstrap I made my own responsive design in css.

```
#heat{ 
background: url(../img/full.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
position: absolute; 
height: 100%;
width: 100%; 
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this..?

```
img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kepLS/)..

Comment: Yee thats what i mean, i updated my post with my code, it does work for me, maybe it's because i use a div instead of img tag?

Comment: As long as you are selecting it properly it doesn't matter whether you use a div or img.. Can you provide an example in jsFiddle of it not working?

Comment: It works now, I used it kinda like you did. I want to but i have one big mess of a code now.. Will clean it when my front page is done.. It kinda works now not perfect but it does the job!

Comment: There is one funny thing, The image is trapped inside a div. however when i re-size the browser it gets a bottom border sort of thing: http://puu.sh/4iwe2.jpg thats the pic. Maybe you know why that is?

Comment: I can't really tell without any coding.. have a live example?

Comment: I will try to make a live example give me a min

Comment: The border is still there.

Comment: Forgot to update the jsFiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/CCdSK/2/ .. all I did was remove the min-height/max-height

Comment: Thank, the "margin-bottom:-6px;" did it!  Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you are using css3 you can use `background-size` property:

`background-size: 100% 100%`

Also you can use the following jquery plugin: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/